# How to combine query results into fixed output format?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm building a Prometheus query (PromQL) to fetch metrics data for monitoring a custom metric on my servers. Some servers may be down at times, and I want to always include such servers in my monitoring output.

I have 2 separate queries for pulling information, like below:

Query 1:

```
up{instance=~"localhost:.+"}
```

Output 1:
The value here indicates that the node is up or down.

| Element | Value |
| --- | --- |
| up{instance="localhost:8080",job="prometheus",monitor="fav-monitor"} | 1 |
| up{instance="localhost:8081",job="prometheus",monitor="fav-monitor"} | 0 |

Query 2:

```
my_node{instance=~"localhost:.+", job="prometheus"}
```

Output 2:

| Element | Value |
| --- | --- |
| my_node{instance="localhost:8080",job="prometheus",monitor="fav-monitor",name="mynode-node1"} | 25 |

I would finally like to obtain my output as below, please help.

| Element | Value |
| --- | --- |
| {instance="localhost:8080",job="prometheus",monitor="fav-monitor",name="mynode-node1"} | 25 |
| {instance="localhost:8081",job="prometheus",monitor="fav-monitor",name="mynode-node2"} | 0 |

NOTE: It is preferable to be able to generate a name for localhost:8081, as in the expected output above, but an empty name would work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the required output with the below query. Improvements and suggestions welcome.

```
(
  up{instance=~"localhost:.+"} 
)
   + on(instance) group_left(name)
(
   my_node{instance=~"localhost:.+", job="prometheus"}
)
  or
(
   label_replace(up{instance=~"localhost:.+"}, "name", "mynode-nodex", "", "") == 0
)
+ on (instance)  group_left(name)
(
   label_replace(up{instance=~"localhost:.+"}, "name", "mynode-nodex", "", "") == 0
)
```